# Hide methods of instance returned to caller

Tags: c++, class, wrapper

In object A there is an array of objects of type B.  Class B has methods B1,B2,...B10

I want object A to have a method which returns a pointer to an object of type B, but only expose methods B9-B10.  The caller should not know about methods B1-B8

How would I hide methods B1-B8 when returning a pointer to object of type B?  I am using C++

UPDATE:

Object A needs access to all the methods of B, but A will only expose methods B9-B10 outside of A.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Make them private?

Comment: You have a few ways of doing this: make the inheritance public, and `use Base::B9` under a private scope, use private inheritance and expose the `B1-B8` under a public scope, or have the class `B` be a private member and write inline wrappers around `B1-B8`. Be warned, the last one may prevent empty-base optimization, and the public inheritance would allow casts to the base class.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a place for the [Proxy Pattern.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) The ProxyB class would only expose B9 - B10.

However, in my opinion if methods B9 and B10 are sufficient then they make a unique interface of their own. Those two methods should be their own class interface. If B was composed of BA with methods B1-B8 and BB with methods B9-B10 then you could just return a pointer to BB.

Comment: I would highly recommend private inheritance if using the proxy pattern, if it is fundamentally important to hide member functions. But that's very easy to do with `using B::B1` under a public scope. Probably the best solution.

Comment: I think this is close to what I want, but am having a little difficulty with the concept.  If A needs access to all methods of B then it cannot just create Bproxy objects.  If A will only create and expose Bproxy, how will it get access to all methods of B?  Should A make 2 lists : one list of B objects, and second list of Bproxy objects (which contain pointer to B and offer subset of methods which call B methods) so that A can access all methods of B, but only return Bproxy objects to callers?  Can you make a small example?

Comment: Do I create object B which derives from B_1_to_8 and from B_9_to_10?  Both base objects would need access to the same member variables.  I'm not sure how to implement this.  I think this is really close to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I can think of is to have another class named `C` whose constructor uses an object of class `B` and provides only methods `B9` and `B10`.

```
class C
{
    private:
        B B_object;
    public:
        C(B i_obj){
            B_object = i_obj;
        }
        void B9_wrapper(){
            B_object.B9();
        }        
        void B10_wrapper(){
            B_object.B10();
        }
}
```

and then your method of `A` which returns a pointer(let's name it `a_method`), has to convert object of `B` to an object of `C` and then return a pointer to the latter object:

```
class A{
    private:
        B arr[10]; // array of objects of B
    public:
        void method_a(){
            // let arr[3] be the object you want to return a pointer of
            C result {arr[3]};
            return &result;
        }
```

hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of different options here, and we should use a proxy pattern, and there are pitfalls with all but one of them.

**Base Class**

Here we have a theoretical, trivial, empty base class with 4 member functions. We want to expose 2 of them.

```
class Base
{
public:
    void b1() {};
    void b2() {};
    void b3() {};
    void b4() {};
};
```

**Public Inheritance, Hide Methods**

If we have a lot of methods that we wish to be public, but only a few we wish to hide, it may be tempting to use public inheritance, and then hide a few methods in the derived class. For example:

```
class Derived1: public Base
{
public:
    char* x() { return x_; }

private:
    using Base::b3;
    using Base::b4;

    char x_[2];
};
```

I would recommend not doing this, since it allows a `static_cast` to the base class, which would allow anyone to treat the class safely as the base class, effectively rendering the derived class a weak suggestion, at best.

**Private Inheritance, Expose Methods**

This is my favorite of the bunch, since it prevents `static_cast` from accessing the base class, and would rely on an implicit, `reinterpret_cast`, or C-style cast try to access the base class (it's still guaranteed by the standard, but is a much stronger suggestion).

```
class Derived2: private Base
{
public:
    using Base::b1;
    using Base::b2;
    char* x() { return x_; }

private:
    char x_[2];
};
```

**Wrapper/Adaptor**

This last attempt prevents all access to the base class, and therefore provides the strongest guarantee, but does so at the potential cost of increased class size (only if the base class is empty):

```
class Wrapper1
{
public:
    void b1() { b_.b1(); }
    void b2() { b_.b2(); }
    char* x() { return x_; }

private:
    Base b_;
    char x_[2];
};
```

**Summary**

All of the above have their advantages, and all have their pitfalls. I would recommend using the second or third option, to wrap the existing class and present a public interface that within reason can only be used with the interface desired.

Comment: I liked the idea of deriving from the base, BUT, A needs access to all methods of B (so it cannot instantiate derived from B objects).  A needs to expose just some of the methods of each B, but hide the rest.